# Check PCRE2 library JIT support during compilation or cmake configuration

Tags: c, cmake, cross-compiling, configure, pcre2

The PCRE2 library provides feature support checks using only a [pcre2_config()](https://github.com/PCRE2Project/pcre2/blob/master/src/pcre2_jit_test.c#L104) function which can be called at runtime like this:

```
int jit = 0;
pcre2_config_8(PCRE2_CONFIG_JIT, &jit);
if (!jit) ...
```

Is there a way for applications to detect missing PCRE2 JIT support at compile time or during cmake configuration, at least when linking the static library ?

When cross-compiling for arm64 on an amd64 host, running a test program from `cmake` probably requires `qemu-user` or another emulator which I'd like to avoid having as a build dependency.